# Handling multiple cursors in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, cursor

I have two cursors (say CRSX1, CRSX2) in a stored procedure. It is like a nested while loop logic I need to implement. Can I use the second cursor CRSX2 while CRSX1 is open or do I have to close the first cursor before using second cursor.

Or is there any other way around if we have to implement logic for double while loop in SQL Server

Thanks in advance

Comment: Best option: get rid of the cursors altogether, if you can ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest cursors, but you should be looking to remove those cursors in favour of a SET-based operation if you can. Otherwise, it's likely performance is not going to be great, especially with larger volumes of data. I'd only use cursors / loop as a last resort.

**Further explanation:**
Using cursors means you will be iterating round, row by row to perform a certain operation (RBAR - Row By Agonizing Row). This is not as efficient as performing the operation in a single, non-looping manner over a set of data in one go (i.e. set-based).

e.g. a crude example, to count the number of rows in a table.

Option 1: Nasty RBAR way, open a cursor on the table, loop round and increment a counter variable.

Option 2: Awesome set-based approach, run a single SELECT such as: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable`

So what I mean, is try to refactor your SQL to find a set-based approach to achieving the result you want. There are generally very few times where a loop/cursor approach can't be replaced by a set-based approach.

Comment: Can you explain in detail what did you mean by SET-based operation.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in [Using nested cursors to produce report output microsoft example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx), you can work with nested cursors.

In sample `vendor_cursor` contains `product_cursor`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the cursors **nested** but you need to declare/open/fetch/close/deallocate the inner cursor within the `WHILE` loop of the outer cursor.